# Is this a correct example of assigning by reference?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a getter method that returns an array declared private.

In .h:

```
    private:
    CStringArray a;
```

In . cpp:

```
    CStringArray &Define::GetDefined()
    {
       return a;
    }
```

In another .cpp:

```
    int size = (define.GetDefined()).GetCount();
```

This does return the right value of int. But is this the correct example of assigning  by reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?"  You said it works.

Comment: yes,..but is this the right example of assigning by reference?

Comment: "assigning by reference" is pretty much meaningless. A reference can only be initialized, not assigned. Any assignment will used the referent, not the reference itself.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so how do I  do it?

Comment: @user1563551: Nothing is being assigned here. It's a correct example of initialising a variable using a reference, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although the extra braces in the final .cpp file are unnecessary and are not helpful to the reader so you should probably not bother

eg.

```
int size = define.GetDefined().GetCount();
```

You should probably also mention that the user should be sure that the object being returned by referance is not allocated on some part of the stack that is about to become invalid.

for example:

```
A& method() {
   return A();
}
```

or any part of memory that is about to become invalid for that matter:

```
class A{
  B member;
  B& get_b_ref() {
    return member;
  }
}

int main() {
  A* a_ptr = new A();
  B& b_ref = a_ptr->get_b_ref();
  delete a_ptr;
  b_ref.any_method(); // yikes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely correct to return reference from the getter.

You might even want to return const Array &, if this object should not be modified from outside